# Flask render template

Tags: python, flask

AIM- to render the html code using flask app

status- the code is running perfectly. But the output is not diplayed. Just white background and no words or anything

the codes are pretty basic

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

#app = Flask(__name__)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "hello world"
    #return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>FlaskTest</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Welcome To GFG</h2>
    <h4>Flask: Rendering Templates</h4>
<!-- this section can be replaced by a child document -->
{% block body %}


<p>This is a Flask application.</p>


{% endblock %}


</body>

</html>
```

index.html is located with in the templates folder

[image]

if we replace the `return render_template('index.html')` with `return "hello world"`   the code is working fine and displaying "hello world"

here is the output of terminal

[image]

I tried even simple html code. But the error persists. Nothing is being displayed when we use render_template. When i use `return "hello world"` it is getting displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem .. We need to save(ctrl+S) the app.py file . After saving, the code is working fine